# Mixed type and mixed array type array Object[] in java not compiling

Tags: java, arrays, object, compiler-errors, mixed

Here is how it looks like

```
public Object[] settings = {true, true, false, 1, true, false, 10, 10, 20, false, false, false, false, false, {true, true, true, true}};
```

Error:

```
 illegal initializer for java.lang.Object
```

In another IDE I get this error.

```
Static Error: Array initializer must be assigned to an array type
```

Comment: `{true, true, true, true}` is not valid Java syntax, except for in `new something[] {true, true, true, true}` or `something[] something = {true, true, true, true}`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Initialize Array like this:

```
public Object[] settings = new Object[]{true, true, false, 1};
```

However, you cannot have arrays and values in the same dimension, because every element in a dimension must of the same type. (Strictly `array '{}'` OR `Object` in our case)

```
new Object[]{true, true, false, 1, {true, false} }; //<--- Illegal initializer
```

---

Instead just use several dimensions and group values in arrays:

```
public Object[][] settings = new Object[][]{{true, true}, {false, 1, 3}};
```

Either use `ArrayList` or `LinkedList` where it is possible to create any array you like.

---

***Update***

In fact it is possible to mix elements like this:

```
new Object[]{true, false, 1, new Object[]{true, false} };
```

Comment: `public Object[] settings = {true, true, false, 1, true, false, 10, 10, 20, false, false, false, false, false, new Object[] {true, true, true, true}};` worked for me thanks